# How to prove the class ListHelper<E> is not thread safe

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I was reading a book 'Java Concurrency in Practice 2nd' recently, the author mentioned if we use Collections.synchronizedList to create a safe thread List,then we must ensure that we are using the same lock which's an Object from SynchronizedCollection.the following code is from the book:

```
public class ListHelper <E> {
    public List<E> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<E>());

    public synchronized boolean putIfAbsent(E x) {
        boolean absent = !list.contains(x);
        if (absent)
            list.add(x);
        return absent;
    }
}
```

in this class, the method putIfAbsent has been locked by an Object from  ListHelper,However list.contains does not use this Object as a lock,there are two locks,so its not safe under multithreading. but my question is how to prove its not thread safe. do you have any ideas?

Comment: Does any other method in this class use `list`? If so, please show that useage.

Comment: no, i just wanna see if the method putIfAbsent is absolutely correct  or not.

Comment: There are 2 objects here. The thread-safety of `ListHelper` is distinct from that of `list`. IMO, `ListHelper` would be thread-safe (instance level) if `list` were not public (which allows `list` to be modified directly between `putIfAbsent`'s `.contains` and `.add` calls on `list`)

Comment: You could put a 20sec sleep after the line `boolean absent = !list.contains(x);` start that thread, along with another that adds the element unconditionally after 10sec.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following code proves that your class is not thread-safe.

It adds 100000 numbers to the list in two different threads:

- `t1` uses the `putIfAbsent` method of your class
- `t2` uses a `synchronized` block to correctly lock the same "mutex" object that `synchronizedList` uses to control access, i.e. the wrapper list itself.

Since both methods are trying to add the *same* 100000 objects, the result should be a list of 100000 objects, i.e. the code should print `100000` at the end.

Sometimes it does, when I run it, but most of the time it's a little higher than that, e.g. `100075`, thereby proving that your `putIfAbsent` is not thread-safe.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ListHelper<Integer> helper = new ListHelper<>();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> Test.t1(helper));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> Test.t2(helper));
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        System.out.println(helper.list.size());
    }
    private static void t1(ListHelper<Integer> helper) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
            helper.putIfAbsent(i);
    }
    private static void t2(ListHelper<Integer> helper) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
            synchronized (helper.list) { // correct way to synchronize
                if (! helper.list.contains(i))
                    helper.list.add(i);
            }
    }
}
class ListHelper <E> {
    public List<E> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<E>());
    public synchronized boolean putIfAbsent(E x) {
        boolean absent = ! list.contains(x);
        if (absent)
            list.add(x);
        return absent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Now lets just hope, he was just curious, instead of you doing all his homework. ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat Good point. Guess I'm not awake enough yet to even think of that. *<yawns>*

Comment: @Andreas I can see that. There aren't many people out there going with your pace. 64K in less than 3 years, very impressive! If it just wouldnt burn out so much ;-)

Comment: dude, its not gonna make it. compiler error occured

Comment: @usher Compiled fine for me. That is a copy/paste from running code.

Answer (score 1):

By ensuring a second thread is run between operations you can show there could be a problem with the first element you add.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class ListHelper<E> {
    public final List<E> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<E>());

    public synchronized boolean putIfAbsent(E x) {
        boolean absent = !list.contains(x);
        runInANotherThread(() -> list.add(x));
        if (absent)
            list.add(x);
        return absent;
    }

    public static void runInANotherThread(Runnable run) {
        Thread t = new Thread(run);
        t.start();
        try {
            t.join(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ListHelper<Integer> list = new ListHelper<>();
        list.putIfAbsent(1);
        System.out.println(list.list);
    }
}
```

prints

```
[1, 1]
```